# How to check the parameters that were used in an NSubstitute mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I know how to assert that a call to a method on a mock interface was done with specific arguments or with any arguments.

However, I want to store the parameter that was used to call the function and run another assert on it, and I could not find anywhere how I can do that.

How can I store the value of the parameter that was used in a call to a mock method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the argument via `Arg.Do` as described in [Performing actions with arguments](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/actions-with-arguments/#performing-actions-with-arguments):

```
var firstArgsBeingMultiplied = new List<int>(); 
calculator.Multiply(Arg.Do<int>(x => firstArgsBeingMultiplied.Add(x)), 10);

calculator.Multiply(2, 10);
calculator.Multiply(5, 10);
calculator.Multiply(7, 4567); //Will not match our Arg.Do as second arg is not 10

Assert.AreEqual(firstArgsBeingMultiplied, new[] { 2, 5 });
```

The arguments can also be accessed and stored from a [`.Returns`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/#callbacks) or [`When..Do`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/) callback.

Hope this helps.